# rewriting rule does not work on jquery.get()?

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, xss

initally, i'm sorry about my question-title, but really nothing better came into my mind....

i've got a .htaccess file that does the "usual" rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

this gives me the possibility of have this url for example **(i'm working with xampp)**:

```
localhost/<project>/en/products/electronic/television/
```

so this url is in the $_GET['url'] variable and i can use it (as an array) to load the controller in my HMVC pattern.

and, to not have to enter the language ("en" in the example above), i've implemented a function that inserts automatically "en". basically that means the following url gives the same controller, and respectively the same output.

```
localhost/<project>/products/electronic/television/
```

but now i wonder, that my javascript files (jquery & co), that are lying in the **folder**

```
<project>/lib/js/query/jquery.min.js
```

can be simply required like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/<project>/lib/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

i expected that the requested path would eventually be something like this (as i add the language in the $_GET['url'] variable and it would try to load a controller and fails...

```
src="/<project>/en/lib/js/jquery/jquery.js"
```

well, in that case i would be glad that it works this way, but it brought me to the idea to try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("this is a test");
    $.get("/<project>/<config-dir>/<config-file>", function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

voila, it outputs the config file.
i think that the behavior will be the same on a productive server, but then just without the "/" nodes in the paths.
how can i prevent this, without moving the config-file from document root?

basically, i've ensured that XSS-attacks won't (almost) be unsuccessful. the "almost" just because there is no 100% safety.

i hope i expressed myself well :)
thanks for the help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i found out, what the problem was, why i could access the config file: the rewrite conditions. they say simply, that the following rule should became effective if the requested filename is not a directory or file or link(?).

```
RewriteEngine On

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    not a directory
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    not a file
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l    not a link(?)

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

so basically this explains, why the rewriting rule did not work on ajax-requests (it did not work on normal requests as well)

now my problem with unallowed access is solved.

to exclude some specific directories from the rewrite rule i added this rule for:

```
RewriteRule ^(<dirname>)($|/) - [L]
```